# Any way to use NotNullWhen with custom return type?

Tags: c#

I have a custom return type `Outcome` that identifies return result. E.g. basic sample function:

```
private Outcome GetSomeEntity([NotNullWhen(true)] out Entity? entity)
{
    entity = GetSomeEntityInternalFunction();
    if (entity == null)
    {
        return Outcome.Fail("Entity is null");
    }
    return Outcome.Success();
}
```

Outcome has implicit bool cast defined:

```
public static implicit operator bool(Outcome o)
{
    return o.IsSuccess;
}

public static bool operator false(Outcome o)
{
    return !o.IsSuccess;
}

public static bool operator true(Outcome o)
{
    return o.IsSuccess;
}
```

However using 'GetSomeEntity' in a function still gives "possible null reference" warning:

```
var outcome = GetSomeEntity(out var entity);
if (!outcome)
{
    return outcome;
}
var entityId = entity.Id; // possible null reference
```

If I change return type to bool, it obviously works. Is there any alternative solution to this so that I don't have to add '!' after entity?

Comment: C# doesn't have such a feature. How about just returning `bool` and adding another `out` parameter for whatever failure information you want to provide? You can mark that as `[NotNullWhen(false)]`. Alternatively, make your `Outcome` generic so that you can do `return Outcome.Success(entity)`, storing the entity inside the `Outcome`, basically.

Comment: I was considering making outcome take a return value, but it wont work with my API due to a lot of code relying on method chaining. e.g. `if (!Fun1(out var val1) || !Func2(out var val2) || !Func3(out var val3) { return Outcome.Fail("yada-yada"): } // then do something with val1/2/3.` else I'd have to break all my sexy method chains up into individual if statements.

Comment: plus sometimes function has multiple multiple out values, and it just adds more confusion

Comment: my initial implementation used `bool Function(out string errorMessage)` pattern, the issue with that is that I have many thousands of functions that have the `out errorMessage` in them and combining errorMessage and bool into `Outcome` struct seemed like a good idea to clean up a lot of this code.

Comment: Well, from a quick analysis, this would be quite a difficult feature to implement. The compiler would at least need to figure out that the expression `Outcome.Success()` causes the true operator to return true, and `Outcome.Fail(...)` causes the true operator to return false. That is a *lot* more static analysis than it currently does.

Answer (score 0):

In instances where a message isn't required (in every example; you discard the message), you can change the signature to just return `T?` directly and simply return `null` to use the pattern match feature. This implementation still allows you to easily chain multiple variables within a single if-statement, with an added benefit that it strictly disallows you to use the variable on the wrong clause.

```cs
if (GetSomeEntity() is not { } entity)
{
    return null;
}
var entityId = entity.Id; // not null!
// rest of the implementation goes here...
```

If you require the message though, then unfortunately you cannot have it both ways. (ignoring implementing custom Roslyn Analyzers that would perform static analysis based on your custom type)

The attributes provided by nullable reference types can only be applied to instances of a singular value; Parameters, and owned fields or properties. This means your only alternative would be to implement what Sweeper suggested, passing the success value into `Outcome`, moving the `out` declaration into a separate method. This should minimize the amount of editing required, by only having to add an infix `().TryGet` in `FooOutcome(out var foo)`, giving you `FooOutcome().TryGet(out var foo)`

```cs
// Outcome{T}.cs
public bool TryGet([NotNullWhen(true)] out T result)
{
    result = IsSuccess ? Success : default;
    return IsSuccess;
}
```

Usage:

```cs
var outcome = GetSomeEntity();
if (!outcome.TryGet(out var entity))
{
    return outcome;
}
var entityId = entity.Id; // not null!
```

This still allows you to keep your method chaining, even if it discards the error messages in this case.

```cs
if (!Func1().TryGet(out var val1) ||
    !Func2().TryGet(out var val2) ||
    !Func3().TryGet(out var val3)
{
    return Outcome.Fail("yada-yada");
}

// Values not null here.
_ = val1.Foo;
_ = val2.Foo;
_ = val3.Foo;
```